# Using an HTML button to call a method ASP .NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I am fetching a set of values from my database. I am using a HTML table to display those fetched values. All these are carried out via a function and I am calling that function from the ASPX page. My question is, How do I call the same function through a button (using the On_Click method) instead of calling it on the aspx page.

C# Code sample :

```
 public string getWhileLoopData()
{
        string htmlStr = "";
        SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection);
        SqlCommand thisCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
        thisCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * from Test";
        thisConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            string Name = reader.GetString(1);
            string Pass = reader.GetString(2);
            htmlStr +="<tr><td>"+id+"</td><td>"+Name+"</td><td>"+Pass+"</td></tr>"                   
        }

        thisConnection.Close();
        return htmlStr;
}
```

ASPX Code sample :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/test.master" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server"  ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder">
    <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" >
        <tr align="left" style="background-color:#004080;color:White;" >
            <td> ID </td>                        
            <td> Name </td>            
            <td>Pass</td>                        
        </tr>

        <%=getWhileLoopData()%>

    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

So basically, I want to place a button on the ASPX page and call `<%=getWhileLoopData()%>` via that button.

Thank You.

Comment: You do not call code behind functions from the page like that. Why not let it load fully in the beginning?

Comment: I needed to use a button to perform a similar fetch operation using the same tables but only with a different query. As in, Suppose I use SELECT * FROM <TABLE> operation at first and for the next one I wanted use a Select query with some where clauses. @Alexander

Comment: Have you tried to just implement a `asp:button` and doing your data (filtering?) on the code behind click event?

Comment: @Alexander I have tried calling it via a button. Though I don't get any errors, the data isn't being displayed on the page at runtime.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a normal `asp.net button` and render the results on a `literal`

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="txtOnMe" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Literal>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

and on code behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtOnMe.Text = getWhileLoopData() ; // "text to show";
}
```

There are also other ways... this is the most close to asp.net

Answer (score -1):

Use repeater for rendering repeated HTML instead of making your HTML string in the code behind file and then rendering it to the .ASPX file. Repeater is fast as well as easy to handle.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/test.master" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server"  ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder">
    <asp:Repeater id="myRpt" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" >
                <tr align="left" style="background-color:#004080;color:White;" >
                    <td> ID </td>
                    <td> Name </td>
                    <td>Pass</td>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
        <td><%# Eval("ID") %></td>
        <td><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
        <td><%# Eval("Pass") %></td>
        </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Content>
```

In your code behind file

```
 SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection);
        SqlCommand thisCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
        thisCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * from Test";
        thisConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();

myRpt.DataSource = reader ;
        myRpt.DataBind();
```

Comment: While technically correct, I don't see what it has to do with the question.

Comment: MAking html from a String object is not a good practice , as concatenating  string in a loop create N number of object reference. that is the not a good approach. @Alexander

Comment: How does it create object references?